# What is the AtTask API beta url

Tags: attask, workfront-api

The [API Docs page](https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003574147-API-Basics) explicitly states:

> Disclaimer - Any use of the API should be tested in AtTask's beta
>   environment prior to being run in the production environment.

I have not been able to find exactly where to access the beta nor other information like authenticating with beta.

Does anyone know how to beta test the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test environment(s) is shown inside workfront. Click setup on the top bar (correct permissions required)
[image]

Select preferences on the side bar:

[image]

Your test environments will be listed at the bottom of the page:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can access this by going to `https://<COMPANY>.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/...`  You can also login to it via the web just like the production environment.  Note, that it refreshed every Friday.  As previously stated you can always check with the CSC as well.

Comment: A bit of necromancy, but according to https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/216668648-Preview-Sandbox-Testing-Environment#accessing-the-preview-sandbox-from-the-workfront-interface the url has been changed to [https://companyname.preview.workfront.com/](https://companyname.preview.workfront.com/)